# create search box for zotero bibliography in XUL

Tags: javascript, xul

I have this block as UI :

```
<textbox id="style-search" flex="1" type="search" timeout="250" dir="reverse"/>
```

and this is the onload function:

```
        var listbox = document.getElementById("style-listbox");
        var searchbox = document.getElementById("style-search");
        var styles = Zotero.Styles.getVisible();
        var index = 0;
        var nStyles = styles.length;
        var selectIndex = null;
        var searchValue = searchbox.value;
    if (searchValue) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nStyles; i++) {
            if (styles[i].title.match(searchValue)) {
                var itemNode = document.createElement("listitem");
                itemNode.setAttribute("value", styles[i].styleID);
                itemNode.setAttribute("label", styles[i].title);
                itemNode.setAttribute("id", styles[i].title);
                if (i % 2 === 0) {
                    itemNode.setAttribute("class", "backG");
                } else {
                    itemNode.setAttribute("class", "backY");
                }
                listbox.appendChild(itemNode);

                if (styles[i].styleID == _io.style) {
                    selectIndex = index;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

i need this: when i type some string in search box i want to filter all my style base on my style list with that string. i try above code but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What *exactly* happens? What are you *expecting* to happen/trying to have happen? What have you done to debug the issue. You are calling functions which you have neither included nor described (or provided a pointer to an external library) (e.g. `Zotero.Styles.getVisible()`). Possibly better would be to supply example data which that call returns, which would make the code in the question more self contained. You also reference elements which are not included in your XUL. Please provide complete, but minimal, code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].